# Spectral measure of a complement

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, normal-operator

Suppose $\mathrm{E}$ is a spectral measure for some normal operator $N$ and $A\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(N))$. I am unable to find an expression of the spectral measure of $A^c:=\sigma(N)\setminus A$ in terms of $\mathrm{E}(A)$.

My conjecture is that the correct expression would be
$$\mathrm{E}(A^c) ~=~ I-\mathrm{E}(A),$$
since this would imply

- $\mathrm{E}(\sigma(N))=\mathrm{E}(A\sqcup A^c)=\mathrm{E}(A)+\mathrm{E}(A^c)=\mathrm{E}(A)+I-\mathrm{E}(A)=I$

as well as

- $\mathrm{E}(\emptyset)=\mathrm{E}(A\cap A^c)=\mathrm{E}(A)\mathrm{E}(A^c)=\mathrm{E}(A)(I-\mathrm{E}(A))=\mathrm{E}(A)-\mathrm{E}(A)^2=\mathsf{0}$, since $\mathrm{E}(A)$ is a projection,

both of which we know to hold for $\mathrm{E}$.

Is my thinking correct?